# Numerical approximation to eigenstates and their differentials

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, adiabatic-model

I am working in Adiabatic Quantum Computing and I have a $6\times6$ Hamiltonian. I have only the symbolic expression for its eigenstates which have complicated expressions in solutions of degree $6$ characteristic polynomial of the Hamiltonian and even ordinary computing over these eigenstates is beyond the power of Mathematica in my computer.
I need to evaluate the **Geometric phases** terms like $\langle\psi_n|\partial _{\phi}|\psi_n\rangle$ where $\phi$ is just a driving adiabatic parameter and $|\psi_n\rangle$ are the solutions to the Hamiltonian.

Now, I can get numerics for $|\psi_n\rangle$ but once I get that, how can I evaluate the differential $\partial_{\phi}|\psi_n\rangle$? 
Or to even approximate it in any form? Because it is impossible to get a manipulative symbolic form for $|\psi_n\rangle$ with such messy calculations, all that can be done is to write Hamiltonian numerically and find the obvious numerical eigenstates.

I have tried using all kinds of Numerical functions available in Mathematica but such a numerical differentiation in one parameter is not possible for this kind of complexity (takes a lot of time).

Comment: There is also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ if you are interested in how to write faster numerics in Mathematica. Like by modifying the precision you demand.